# how to resolve noModuleFound error for pytorch in python

Tags: pytorch, modulenotfounderror, large-language-model

Error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 1
----> 1 import torch
      2 device = "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"
      3 print(device)

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'
```

and I have installed pytorch using pip3:

```
pip3 install torch --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu118
```

I have already checked in the lib folder of cuda and torch is present over there but I don't know why it is not fetching it from there

Comment: It could be a mismatch of the system version of python.
I recommend to install `pyenv`  https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv and create a virtual environment per project, in order to not compromise the python version of the system.